# How do I fix my window that doesn't lock?

Tags: windows

First time home owner and I'm not sure what the previous owner did to install/fix this window.

It currently does not lock which seems to be because the upper window does not go all the way up. Seems like they installed some screws on both sides inside the frame to hold it up but they aren't high enough for the lock to meet.

How do I fix this?

Cold air flows fairly easily since it doesn't lock.

[image: Screw holding top window]

[image: Window Lock]

[image: Top of Window]

Comment: Also, for future reference, each pane of glass and the wood around it are called a "sash". If only the bottom sash moves, it's a "single-hung" window. If both sashes move, as yours do, it's called a "double-hung" window. Knowing the correct terms helps you feel smarter when asking questions. :D We all had to learn at some point.

Comment: I thought that screws like that were to prevent the window being forced open from the outside as an anti-burglary measure.

Answer (score 1):

Either the top sash hasn't been pushed all the way up, or the bottom sash isn't pushed all the way down. Therefore, the locks don't meet in the middle.

The 3rd picture looks like the sash might be broken in the corner and may have had a (poor) DIY repair. It appears that the top rail of the sash has a round-over on the inside corner, while the vertical, left-side rail is a much more square profile. Additionally, the wood doesn't meet at the corners.

You may have to pull that sash down and take a good look at it. Does it look factory original? Is the top rail of the sash actually horizontal? It looks like the right corner of the sash might be lifted up some. If that's the case, that corner may be hitting the top of the window frame before the rest of the window, blocking it from closing all the way. If that's the case, the sash itself may need to be (properly) repaired (the subject of a whole new question). If this is the bottom sash, it's causing the lock rail to be raised up and that's why it's not meeting the other half of the lock mechanism.

The screws into the jams below the top sash are just a hack job at an attempt to hold the window closed and, obviously, aren't doing a sufficient job. If it does look like the sash will need to be repaired, though, the screws may be the best you can do for now to hold the sash. To stop the cold air flow until nicer weather arrives and/or you get the sash repaired (you may want to wait for nicer weather), stuff soft foam into whatever gaps you can find where air is getting through. Do *NOT* use spray foam! This is a temporary fix and you want to be able to cleanly remove the foam once the sashes are fixed properly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the prior repair was done to keep the top sash up. That sash appears to be missing pivot bars that would connect it to a part called a balance, which is the mechanism that allows you to smoothly raise and lower a window without it falling. It also looks like the sash may need to be replaced or put back together. You can see an example of the balance repair [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=W-7oKXr7vHU).

I had to repair some broken pivot bars on a Harvey window recently and was able to use the warranty to have them send replacement parts for only shipping cost. Repair videos are on their YouTube channel. You might get similarly lucky, but your product is definitely different than mine.

Your warranty/install info is typically in a sticker attached to the inner part of the frame. It may be hidden by the top sash. Warranty claims can be filed [here](https://harveywindows.com/parts-and-support/warranty). Edit: no relationship to Harvey. Have just completed a repair on one of my home’s windows.

Good luck!

Comment: This is great advice if one happens to have a "Harvey" window that's still under warranty, but there's no indication that this is the OPs situation. This feels more like spam for Harvey than a good, general answer. Based on previous Q&As, I'll give the benefit of the doubt that this isn't intended to be spam (either that or you're really good at the long game!) You may want to [edit] to indicate your relationship with "Harvey".

Comment: No relationship with Harvey other than the house I bought has a few of their windows - just noticed the brand and wanted to share how to make a claim since I did this a few months ago. My window’s warranty doesn’t expire, which made me think OP might be similarly situated, but I don’t know if the lifetime warranty applies OP’s product.

Comment: [Edit] that into your answer so it doesn't get lost/overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a lot of improvements could be made, but here's a solution for the specific problem of the two parts of the lock not matching up.

- Unscrew the part that is too low.
- Cut a piece of thin wood or sheet vinyl to the same size as its base.
- Drill two holes in it to match the screw holes.
- Place the new piece under the original part and screw it into place.
- It should now be high enough that the latch can now be turned into it.

The overall result won't be as good as the original (i.e. at least one of the sashes still doesn't fully close), but the two sashes will now properly lock together to prevent their being opened (or slipping open).

Comment: OP indicated that air is leaking around the sashes. That's because the sashes aren't closing all the way. This will get the locking mechanism to function, but it's just a poorly applied band-aid that won't fix the heart of the problem - air flow through the window when not desired.

Comment: @FreeMan, right. I was simply providing a quick fix for the specific Title question, not for a full repair of the situation. I've had old houses where the frame has twisted slightly, creating the same latching problem (even though the sashes still seal properly). Also, the OP said that the air leaks were "*since it doesn't lock*".

Comment: I suppose that if the issue is air coming through _only_ at the sash meeting rail, getting the lock to pull the sashes tighter by shimming the lock up higher might fix the issue. This is definitely a solution for "can't lock", it _might_ be a solution for "air coming through" - not enough info from the OP to know for sure.